# Propositional Logic (equivalence exercise)

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am working on the following exercise:
$$
(\exists a \in M_1:A_1(a))\Rightarrow(\exists b \in M_2:A_2(b)) \equiv \exists b \in M_2 \exists a \in M_1:(A_1(a) \Rightarrow A_2(b))
$$

I have been working on this for a while now however, I am always stuck at a certain point. From whichever angle I approach the problem, I simply won't get forward. (working from left to right)

This is where I am stuck:
$$
\exists a \in M_2 :(\forall a\in M_1:(A_1(a) \Rightarrow A_2(b)))
$$
Tips are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: The equivalence is wrong!

Comment: Do you have to prove the equivalence $\equiv$ ?

Comment: I don't think they are equivalent. Let $M_1 = \{x, y\}$ such that $A_1(x)$ and $\neg A_1(y)$, and $M_2 = \{z\}$ with $\neg A_2(z)$. Then the right side is true: take $b = z$ and $a = y$. However, the left side is false. Because there is $a \in M_1$ s.t. $A_1(a)$ (namely $a = x$), while there is no $b \in M_2$ with $A_2(b)$.

Comment: I guess so too. I worked on this for 2 hours now and I just can't get to the right side.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(\exists a \in M_1:A_1(a))\Rightarrow(\exists b \in M_2:A_2(b)) \\
\equiv (\neg\exists a \in M_1:A_1(a))\vee(\exists b \in M_2:A_2(b))\\
\equiv \exists b \in M_2:[(\neg\exists a \in M_1:A_1(a))\vee(A_2(b))]\\
\equiv \exists b \in M_2:[(\forall a \in M_1:\neg A_1(a))\vee A_2(b)]\\
\equiv \exists b \in M_2:\forall a \in M_1:[\neg A_1(a)\vee A_2(b)]\\
\equiv \exists b \in M_2:\forall a \in M_1:[ A_1(a)\Rightarrow A_2(b)]\\
\not\equiv \exists b \in M_2:\exists a \in M_1:[A_1(a) \Rightarrow A_2(b)]
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be $$(\neg\exists a \in M_1: \neg A_1(a))\vee(\exists b \in M_2:A_2(b))\\$$

Comment: No absolutely no, the negeation if used, then it gives $\forall a \in M_1: \neg A_1(a)$